# I can't use sublime compile latex file

Tags: latex

when i use sublime to compile latex file,subliem always get Error.
and the message is:
***SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character***
but the file is correct,because i can compile it with other editor.
the sample I get from other can't compile either.and the Errorcode is same.

```
\documentclass{artilcle}
\begin{document}
HelloWorld
\end{document}
```

Does anyone can help me with this question? my Window and IOS encounter the problems.

Comment: `\documentclass{artilcle}`contains a typo, it should be `\documentclass{article}`

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/306355/why-do-i-only-get-this-error-on-one-of-my-computers-and-not-the-rest/306424

Comment: Emmmm, i type the wrong CODE,when the code is correct , it can't be compiled correctly.QAQ.